# How can I push my Xamarin Forms code changes to all my dev devices at once?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app, which I'm testing in  2 android devices and 2 iOS devices, all connected to my mac.
I'm doing some rapid iterations in the code (GPS, ActivityTracking, etc) and then I'm deploying to all devices, one by one:

1. Android -> Debug -> Google Pixel 2
2. Android -> Debug -> LG Nexus 5
3. iOS -> Debug -> Oscar's iPhone
4. iOS -> Debug -> Oscar's iPad Pro

Selecting each device one by one and push the code takes some time.

**Is there a way to push to all?**

I don't need a debugger attached, just the new code on all devices.

I'm using the latest version of VS for Mac.

Even a command-line solution will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use either AppCenter, with different Groups and auto update (force) or, use different build configs.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I'm sure my DevOps person will help me with this.
AppCenter looks like an option worth pursuing if I cannot push directly from the mac to the connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 devices, one per project (Android and iOS) it can be done by creating a Run configuration to Launch Multiple Projects.

To set multiple startup projects

1. Right-click the solution node and then select Options
2. Navigate to Run->Configurations and create a new one
   [image]
3. Under Devices select both projects and press OK.
   [image]
4. Select the new Solution Run Configuration as the active run configuration. Make sure both projects appear in bold.
   [image]
5. Press run and both project will execute on the target devices

Here a video of the steps to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-0qOgyRVrY

This is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-startup-projects?view=vsmac-2019